# Maven : mvn install results to Compilation failure

Tags: maven, compiler-errors, installation

When running the command "mvn clean", it returns a build success but when running "mvn install", it returns Compilation failure. Could you please help me out to trace what causing the error? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT : Added logs.**

```
[ERROR] \Users...\workspace\project\src\main\java\c
om\project\Interceptor.java:[30,22] cannot find symbo
l
symbol  : variable HttpServletResponse
location: class com.project.Interceptor
[INFO] 49 errors
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.730s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Mar 08 11:14:16 CST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/24M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.
3.2:compile (default-compile) on project project: Compilation failure: Co
mpilation failure:
[ERROR] \Users...\workspace\project\src\main\java\c
om\project\Interceptor.java:[3,25] package javax.serv
let.http does not exist
[ERROR] \Users...\workspace\project\src\main\java\c
om\project\Interceptor.java:[4,25] package javax.serv
let.http does not exist
[ERROR] \Users...\workspace\project\src\main\java\c
om\project\Interceptor.java:[26,26] cannot find symbo
l
......
[ERROR] symbol  : variable HttpServletResponse
[ERROR] location: class com.project.Interceptor
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal o
rg.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on
 project mobile-gateway: Compilation failure
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:213)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje
ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje
ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBu
ild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(Lifecycl
eStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Laun
cher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.jav
a:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(La
uncher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:
352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilationFailureException: Compilation fail
ure
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompiler
Mojo.java:656)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(Default
BuildPluginManager.java:101)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:209)
        ... 19 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureExc
eption
```

**EDIT 2 : By the way, I'm using Eclipse Indigo IDE and Glassfish 3.1.**

Comment: `[ERROR] symbol  : variable HttpServletResponse`
`[ERROR] location: class com.project.Interceptor`
Is the problem, but you haven't included the vital part of the output that gets specific with the compile error. `mvn clean` deletes any traces of previous builds, so it's rare that it fails, `mvn install` actually starts compiling your Java, so if you have a problem in the code, it will produce a compile error like you are getting.

Comment: @SpellingD, thanks for the input. I used "import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;" and it doesn't produce any compile error in the code after saving, but after runnning "mvn install", it does.

Comment: You should include the part of the log that has the first occurrence of the error, before `BUILD FAILURE`. It should be in the block of text following `Building <project name>`.

Comment: @SpellingD, logs updated. I don't know why the HttpServletResponse cannot be found. Do I need to add something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing some Java EE dependencies, try adding the following dependency to your pom.xml (you probably need more):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I added it in pom.xml and it works. But why does it have to be in pom.xml? I already included the ServerRuntime library GlassFish 3.1 and javax.servlet is already there but still, it cannot be found?

Comment: @iamthe.exception, According to your maven output, servlet-api.jar is required at compile time, which usually means you have some classes that explicitly import the package javax.servlet.http and use the class HttpServletResponse. Adding it to GlassFish lib folder is only for GlassFish to resolve it at runtime.

Comment: You should define a scope for it. <scope>provided</scope>, cause it will be packaged into your artifact (war).